# How do I sort a list of char * in c++ alphabetically?

Tags: c++, sorting

So I have a list of char * that is storing words from a text file.

```
char* tempWord = new char[20];
list<DT> list1= new <DT>list();
while (!cin.eof()) {
     cin >> tempWord;
     list1.push_back(tempWord);
}
list1.sort();
```

But the sort is not working. It is not sorting. If I add APPLE APPIE APPLS in the txt, I get the same after sort, I should be getting APPIE APPLE APPLS. Any ideas why or how do I sort it?

Comment: `list<DT> list1= new <DT>list();` this hardly looks like C++.

Comment: Odd syntax notwithstanding, try a custom comparator (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort), e.g. `list.sort([](const char *fst, const char *snd) { return strcmp(fst, snd) < 0; });`

Comment: Why not use `std::string` for the words ?

Comment: May be API restrictions, making a `std::string` out of a provided `const char *` is an unnecessary allocation. If possible `std::string` would be preferable, but bear in mind this may not be possible for all cases.

Comment: What do  you want to sort by? Length or something else?

Comment: You didn't give the context, but for most use-case `std::vector` is preferable over `std::list`. Some more info here: https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/06/stroustrup-lists.

Comment: For words use std::string, not new char[20]. Put the words in a std::vector<std::string> and use std::sort from <algorithm> to do your sorting. Oh and learn to type std:: instead of using "using namespace std"

Comment: `list<DT> list1 = new<DT> list();` ... this looks like something I'd expect coming from a java programmer trying out C++. Just do `list<DT> list1;` - you nearly never need to use `new` / `delete` in modern C++.

Comment: In general if you have to type new/delete in C++ you might need to think again, Either use an STL datatype directly or if you have to allocate memory use std::make_unique. I know most people start learning datastructures using C++ (with a lot of new/delete and pointers), but that's not the same as learning C++ as it should be used.

Comment: Also read: [Why is `iostream::eof()` inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: **Never** do this: `char* tempWord = new char[20]; cin >> tempWord;` since it will write out of bounds if anyone enters a word longer than 19 `char`s. The overload that takes a `char*` was removed in C++20 for this reason and replaced by an overload that takes a reference to a `char[N]` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Closer to what you want.

```
std::string s;
vector<string> vec;

while (cin >> s) {
     vec.push_back(s);
}

std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

Comment: `std::ranges::sort(vec);` is even better